# Postgres rule to substitute word in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, select, substitution, rules

Is it possible to replace a word within a WHERE clause of a SELECT statement by a rule (`CREATE RULE myrule AS ON SELECT TO mytable`...)?

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM mytable
WHERE col2 = 1;
```

Should become

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM mytable
WHERE col3 = 1;
```

The initial statement is issued by a client which does not allow the substitution. Hence the substitution has to be done on the database side.

** edit **

I might not have been specific enough.
I need a column name substitution for this kind of pattern of the select statement. The WHERE clause constantly changes. As well as the 
Is it possible to refer to the current SELECT statement in the rule itself?

Broken down to the bare minimum this is what I need:

- take the current SELECT statement (if it has this certain pattern)
- replace "WHERE col2" with "WHERE col3"
- packed into a rule which can be deployed on the database side of things

Comment: You can make the SQL dynamic, where you pass all three parameters (rather than literals) and then handle it so that when it gets a blank parameter it becomes true...  for example `where (col1 = ? or ? is null) and (col2 = ? or ? is null)`

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you could set the rule then the query will return `col1, col3` instead of `col1, col2`.

Comment: thats why the substitution in my example includes the WHERE in order to make sure only the table name in the WHERE clause would get replaced

Answer (score 1):

Use `case when` statement

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM mytable
WHERE CASE WHEN foo='bar' THEN col3 ELSE col1 END = 1;
```